# How to get display devices name in Linux

Tags: c, linux

I'd like to find linux analogs of [EnumDisplayDevices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumdisplaydevicesw) and [EnumDisplaySettingsEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumdisplaysettingsexw) WinAPI functions.

The info I need to get is display name and state (if it active or not), width, height, bits per pixel and frequency.
How can I get this info using C (C++)?
Thanks.

Comment: You have to go through [the X window system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System_protocols_and_architecture).

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by 'Some programmer dude' in the comments you can have to go through the X window system. Most specifically one option would be the RandR protocol. Here is the [protocol specification](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/proto/randrproto/tree/randrproto.txt) as well as the source code of the command [xrandr](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/xrandr/tree/xrandr.c) that invokes the XRR functions and outputs most of the info that you want on the terminal. Look for the place where the

```
XRRScreenResources  *res
```

is populated and then how the modes are fetched from it using the find_mode() function.

other commands that might assist you and don't go over the RandR extensions could be xprop(1), xdpyinfo(1), xwininfo(1)

Answer (score 2):

Some programmer dude and ramrunner are absolutely correct.  For most Linux systems, the graphical "desktop" is based on X Windows. Command-line tools for querying your X "display" include [xrandr](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/xrandr.1.html) and [xdpyinfo](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xdpyinfo).  The C-language source code for both are freely available; you can find many example programs with a Google search.

... HOWEVER ...

X Windows is "client/server".  Your Linux "desktop" need *not* be on your physical PC; your X "display" could just as easily be a Windows desktop.  In this case - xrandr and xdpyinfo are still applicable: they refer to *where you're displaying* (e.g. an XMing client on Windows), and *not* the physical host Linux is running on.

If you *want* to query the graphics devicews on your *physical* server ... then you'll instead use commands like [lshw -c display](https://linux.die.net/man/1/lshw) or [get-edid](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/get-edid.1.html)

Comment: very good point! may i add that on BSD systems you can use wsconsctl to get the display.width and .height, as well as on all you could parse the output of dmesg to figure out the vga adapters and physical monitors if they properly report their identifiers. these are independent of the X window system.

Comment: My Linux machine is a host for own RDP client. Remote user connects to the linux machine. To share display I need to get info about this display. Host machine might be either Linux virtual machine or Linux physical machine. So, as I understand you correctly, X Windows System - is not what I need to get display info in my case?